# **error message /Users/yyyyyy/.zshenv:.:1: no such file or directory: /Users/yyyyyy/.cargo/env**

Tags: macos, shell, sh, zsh

**error message `/Users/yyyyyy/.zshenv:.:1: no such file or directory: /Users/yyyyyy/.cargo/env`

any tips? need help. thanks in advance!
my Z shell .zsh and .zshenv went missing in MacOS Terminal. any ideas on how to resolve? it was there and then poofff

Comment: It's implausible that _.zshenv went missing_ if there's an error in it.

Comment: what do i need to do?

Comment: thanks for replying!  do i need        /Users/yyyyyy/.cargo/env

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't judge what you really need. If you want to get rid of the error message, you can comment out or remove the respective line (apparently 1) from `.zshenv`; if you need .cargo/env, you surely will notice sooner or later.

Comment: @AlejSala : The error message gives the exact source of the error, line 1 of `/Users/yyyyyy/.zshenv`. You would have to show us the content of this line, i.e. do a  `head -n 1 /Users/yyyyyy/.zshenv`.